# How to extract objects from an image svg?

Tags: xml, image-processing, svg

Here is the image i convert from .jpeg to svg and i want to detect the objects on the image such as  the car , the window...[image: maison.jpg][image: !]Iam not familiar with the structure of the file so i haven't understand what are these numbers and how can i use them to classify the image

Comment: I doubt that's possible. It's highly unlikely that the car or the window is a single object.

Comment: Don't! There is no value in converting the image to SVG if you want to train a machine-learning system. There are hundreds of libraries that will help you train CV on bitmaps and exactly none that will do the same for SVG. That image is complex so it won't give a discrete "window" path just lots of fragments that may or may not be part of a larger object.

Comment: For your reference though the numbers after `fill:#` represent colors and the numbers in `d="..."` represent points forming a closed path where the path is a segment of a single color. Each of these segments is likely to be very small because the image contains very few areas of solid color (even shades of white are different colors).

Comment: I know it's more easy to extract  objects  from a raster image and i already found some librairies but in my case i'am working  in my thesis  on a problematic  where i have to analyse the image in text format  and since xml is not  an image format i I thought of using svg

Answer (score 0):

Some samples to understand better!

- [Intro about SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp)
- [Document Struct](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html)
- [HTML5 and SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp)
- [SVG Graphics XML](https://www.xul.fr/en-xml-svg.html)
- [How to extract an embedded image frmo a SVG file](https://superuser.com/questions/299977/how-to-extract-an-embedded-image-from-a-svg-file)
- [Here you understand each element of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)